# State Sync in for Hyperledger Fabric using LEVELDB?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Reading the docs ,I understand that there are two options to maintain the world state LEVELDB and COUCHDB .

In case of LevelDB ,"LevelDB is the default state database embedded in the peer node" I am assuming it is local to a peer . As in every peer has a copy of LevelDB running .

In case of CouchDB there is a separate container to run it ,and all the peers can use it to execute transactions (all the peers see the same data )

1. In the first case for LevelDB ,how is the version of the data synced across all the peers?
2. Is this a plug and play feature , Can I for
       example use an ETCD cluster ,instead of CouchDB ?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's actually the same for both LevelDB and CouchDB.  The database is basically used as a persistent last know value store.  It can be rebuilt at any time for the ledger (the block chain) which is actually what is replicated across all peers via the ordering service

**EDIT**  To clarify, peers receive blocks from the orderer.  Each peer than validates the transactions in each block and for each valid transaction it will update the state in the database.  In the case of LevelDB, it's an embedded call and in the case of CouchDB the peer communicates with CouchDB via the CouchDB HTTP API.  Of course it also writes the blocks to the ledger files on disk as well.

2. It's not plug and play ... only LevelDB and CouchDB are currently supported.  The codebase itself supports adding additional databases, but someone would need to implement the support in the actual codebase.

Comment: The blockchain itself is a file with the list of transactions ,right . So I understand correctly ,it doesn't matter if its a separate container or present on each peer separately , it just reads the updates from the blockchain ,and stores the latest values or the keys ?

Comment: Added more detail to my answer above